# Dynamically populate jQuery Mobile list view content

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I currently am using a dynamically generated list view in jQuery mobile to display a bunch of data from a database. Although most of this content is in the database and generated by django before the page is loaded, there is also some content I'd like to insert into the list view elements that is stored using HTML5 localStorage.

As a result, this data can only be accessed via javascript, not the django backend. I envision binding some javascript to the `pagebeforecreate` event. After this, I need to somehow loop through all of the `li` elements within the `ul` (I have its `id`), except the first (since thats the divider).

After that it gets a bit tricky. Assume that I have an array already loaded up in javascript that has fetched the info from localStorage. Call it `classNames`. I've assigned a custom property period index, to each `li` identifying which index of the `classNames` array the given `li` should receive as text.

**UPDATE**

For example this the contents of a given list with look like before being enhanced by query.

```
    <li data-role="list-divider">Regular Schedule/li>
    <li periodindex="5" type="schedule">
        <h1 class="ui-li-heading">6</h1>
        <p class="ui-li-maintext"><i>class name goes here</i></p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>7:30</b> - <b>8:30</b></p>
        <p class="ui-li-count">60</p>
    </li>
    <li periodindex="3" type="schedule">
        <h1 class="ui-li-heading">6</h1>
        <p class="ui-li-maintext"><i>class name goes here</i></p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>8:45</b> - <b>9:50</b></p>
        <p class="ui-li-count">65</p>
    </li>
   <li periodindex="7" type="schedule">
        <h1 class="ui-li-heading">6</h1>
        <p class="ui-li-maintext"><i>class name goes here</i></p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>10:00</b> - <b>12:00</b></p>
        <p class="ui-li-count">120</p>
    </li>
   <li periodindex="0" type="schedule">
        <h1 class="ui-li-heading">6</h1>
        <p class="ui-li-maintext"><i>class name goes here</i></p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><b>1:00</b> - <b>4:00</b></p>
        <p class="ui-li-count">180</p>
    </li>
```

I need a way to loop through all the given `li` elements and replace the contents of "class name goes here" with the contents of the classNames array object at index specified by the `periodindex` property of the `li` element. Note also that the first `li` element in the list should be ignored as it is the title of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `classNames` array is in the same order as the `LI` elements appear in your page, try this:

**Updated as per OPs responses**

```
for (var i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
    $("#schedule li[periodindex='" + i + "']").find(".ui-li-maintext").html("<i>" + classNames[i] + "</i>");
}
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't very clear about this. I mean that the number of `li` elements does not necessarily have to correspond with the length of the classNames array. There may be 1 or potentially 20 `li` elements. The thing that identifies which index of the classNames array the given `li` element is interested in is referenced by the `periodindex=` aspect of the `li` tag. I've updated the question to show a sample list.

Comment: No problem, I've amended my answer.

Comment: ohhh i see. ok so each given instance of the loop may indeed hit on more than one list element. perfect. the beauty of jquery

Comment: is there anyway to localize it to just the daughter elements of a specific HTML element? let's say the list lives within a div with `id=schedule`.

Comment: There is indeed, see amended answer again.

Comment: you rock, exactly what i was looking for